# R: ggplot2 - Label prints every row like a blur, instead of just the sum of the values

Tags: r, ggplot2

i just need to put the sum of "sessions" of top of each bar. But i just get this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
ggplot(VisitasData, aes(factor(Fuentes), sessions, fill = Fuentes)) + 
        geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
        geom_text(aes(label = comma(sessions)), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
        scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("0", "1", "3", "6", "9"),
                          labels = c("Directo", "Email", "References",
                                     "SEO", "Social Media"),
                          values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", 
                                     "#F0E442", "#0072B2"))
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample of your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be certain without seeing your data, but here's what appears to be happening, illustrated with some fake data:

```
# Fake data
set.seed(23)
dat = data.frame(cat=rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=4), value=sample(100:1000, 12))

   cat value
1    A   619
2    A   300
3    A   398
4    A   738
5    B   835
6    B   479
7    B   962
8    B   974
9    C   850
10   C   988
11   C   871
12   C   724

# Analogous to your plot
ggplot(dat, aes(cat, value, fill=cat)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", alpha=0.25) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=value))
```

[image]

What happened above is that `ggplot` added a bar for every single row of data. As a result, there are four bars overplotted, as you can see because of the `alpha=0.25` parameter, which makes the bars transparent. `ggplot` did this because of `stat="identity"` which tells `ggplot` to take the data as is and not apply any transformations. But without `stat="identity"`, `geom_bar` will throw an error, because the default `stat` for `geom_bar` is `stat="bin"` (meaning create a histogram of row counts) and you can't map a variable to `y` and also use `stat="bin"` (and a histogram isn't what you want anyway).

Instead, you need to tell `ggplot` to sum the values within each category first and then plot the sums. For example:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(cat, value, fill=cat)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom="bar", position="dodge") + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom="text", aes(label=..y..))
```

[image]

You can also create a summary data frame outside of `ggplot` and then feed the summary data frame to `ggplot`. Then you would use `geom_bar(stat="identity")` to get the bar plot you want.

Comment: Thanks @eipi10, i did a summarise from dplyr, and then plot the graph. Thanks again.